# Magento Remove "Miscellaneous Scripts" from CMS Page

Tags: xml, magento

I've been trying to remove the "Miscellaneous Scripts" (set in `System > Configuration > General > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts`) for a particular CMS page.  I've gone to `CMS > Pages > Design > Page Layout > Layout Update XML` and entered the following code:

```
<reference name="head">
   <remove name="miscellaneous-scripts"/>
</reference>
```

This doesn't seem to remove the code from the CMS page.  I've tried similar variations such as "header" instead of "head", however, none have worked as of yet.  Will somebody please help me in achieving this?  Can this successfully be done using this method?  Thank you in advance for any constructive contributions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Evan's answer, I have decided to directly edit the template page.  I needed to exclude the "Miscellaneous Scripts" on the "Empty" layout.  So I went to `/app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/page/empty.phtml`.  From there, I did a string replace to remove the code from getChildHtml('head').

Changed:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('head');
```

To this:

```
$headcode = str_replace('<script type="text/javascript" ...>', '', $this->getChildHtml('head'));
echo $headcode;
```

Now, the code will be excluded only from empty.phtml.

Comment: I don't think I've seen evidence of that kind of manipulation in core.  I would recommend that you create a new head.phtml and use layout xml to switch between the two.  In the new head.phtml, you can omit the getIncludes().  String manipulations on getChildHtml() somehow feels dirty to me.

Answer (score 1):

Misc. scripts are made available via [Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head getIncludes()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php#L473)
which is called from [template/page/html/head.phtml](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml#L45).  Because it's called directly from the template and not via getChildHtml(), you can't use layout xml to remove it using a `<remove name... />` tag.

You could set a new head.phtml template which doesn't call getIncludes() for that CMS page using layout.  Or you could rewrite Html/Head.php and expose a method for disabling includes.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  Since that is the case, I will manually edit the layout file in which I want to exclude that code.  My answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

I "invented" a simple trick to remove misc-html from cms or whatever:

In the content insert the following html code:

```
<style>
.misc-html {display:none}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove directly from layout, but in you example you write wrong xml for remove this block.
This block is in `container="before.body.end"` and name of "Miscellaneous Scripts" is "absolute_footer"

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <referenceBlock name="absolute_footer" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```